# what are the names of the glyphs in Segoe UI Symbol used for icons

Tags: windows-8, fonts

Windows 8 comes with a new font Segoe UI Symbol. The font has many icons in the range U+E000 - U+EF013 that can be used for buttons when building apps for Windows store.

Where is the list of names of these symbols?

There are plenty of posts about this topic, but none seem to have a list of names.

Jeremy Likeness [Windows 8 Icons: Segoe UI Symbol](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/windows-8-icons-segoe-ui-symbol.html)

Jeremy Foster [Windows 8 App Bar Icons (from Segoe UI)](http://www.codefoster.com/post/2012/08/18/win8icons.aspx)

Jerry Nixon [Windows 8: 1,000 Metro icons you already have installed](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/03/windows-8-1000-metro-icons-you-already.html)

Comment: jonathantoine has a list of names in his [winjs post](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2012/03/05/winjs-out-of-the-box-available-icons/), but doesn't cite his reference.

Comment: Since these are in the private use area, they do not have standard names.

Comment: bless my sweet lucky stars. @raymondchen commented on my post! I think they do have names. I doubt the font designer referred to every glyph as 'Private Use'

Comment: I'd probably be ok with the names from the standard Windows Store project templates in VS2012. Lots of "Standard AppBarButton Styles" in StandardStyles.xaml. Unless someone knows the people who manage the fonts in the Windows distribution, this may be as close as we can come for a 'standard' list of names.

Comment: You might also want to check the XAML Candy app in the store, it has one section dedicated to Segoe UI Symbol.

Comment: wow @SorinComanescu, that's a great suggestion. That app is proper tidy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This official page has a list of names
[Segoe UI Symbol icon list (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I got tired of messing with these icons one at a time by their character codes, so I started a [reusable master stylesheet](https://github.com/geekytime/segoe-symbol-css) based on the names listed in [this Dev Center Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx).

Feel free to use it in your Windows 8 apps.

(Full disclosure: I stole this idea, and most of the CSS code from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).)

Answer (score 1):

Do a search (on Windows 8, it's Windows key + Q) for the "Character Map" app (it's included with Windows).  It should open in the desktop.  For the Font dropdown, select "Segoe UI Symbol".  Then you can click on each symbol and at the bottom, their name and "U+E000" number is displayed.

Comment: Jennifer - I'm using windows Version 6.2.9200. Charmap only shows U+E000 Private Use

Comment: That range is the [private use area](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf), so my take is that "if" they had names they would be font specific, in which case the names in standardstyles.xaml seem just as good as anything else.

Comment: JJS - I'm sorry.  There are a bunch of other symbols with font names provided; I missed that you were specifically looking for private use ones.  Those do not have names.  From the [link that Jim provided](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf): "The Private Use Area does not contain any character assignments, consequently no character code charts or names lists are provided for this area."

Comment: @JenniferMarsman-MSFT I posted an answer that has the official list of names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find this useful and a preferable way to find glyphs in the Segoe UI Symbol font (or any font for that matter): I built a [Character Map app](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/32502afd-89cf-4afa-ab64-04fe49dc0bd1) for the Windows 8 store that is much better than the Character Map program that ships with Windows. It is made primarily for developers looking for icons, has a number of other nice bells and whistles and is fully open source. Hope you enjoy!

Comment: Great App! Good job, helped me find the symbol I wanted!